# Google Chrome rendering issue, position: fixed

Tags: html, css

I have been developing a website and I have had no problems at all with it. I am now testing it on different PC's and am having a problem where the rendering breaks in google chrome. The pc's all run the same versions of chrome which is version 21.0.1180.89. On some pc's the page renders perfectly and on others, the position: fixed property is completely ignored and me page header disappears when scrolling. On inspecting the element with the chomr developer tools it says the element is there but the element is not visible. It is not a problem with z-index since I set this really high and did not fix it.

Where do I even start to look for a reason for this problem? Is this a css issue or an issue with the browser?

Thanks in advance

**Edit:**

The solution was found. I had set opacity: 0.99 on the body element of the document in an attempt to fix a problem with fonts displaying incorrectly on Mac's. This should be a valid css property? However it seems that on some browsers this caused the page to reder incorrectly.

Comment: Link to your page so we can debug as well, perhaps?

Comment: Assigning an opacity value less than 1 to a positioned element implicitly creates a stacking context. See the last paragraph here http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#transparency . You could also read this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Understanding_z-index/The_stacking_context .

Comment: if you found a solution yourself then put it on the answer section and accept it. so only the question will be close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was found. I had set opacity: 0.99 on the body element of the document in an attempt to fix a problem with fonts displaying incorrectly on Mac's. This should be a valid css property? However it seems that on some browsers this caused the page to reder incorrectly.

Comment: i also have this issue, in my condition their are white boxes behind my background, i tried your fix, after this whole background becames white...